# Handling session-based authentication between Node.js and Django

Tags: python, node.js, django, authentication, session

This may edge upon a "best practice" type of question, but I'd like to explain my approach, list out my hypotheses and get constructive feedback.

Currently, my setup consists of two servers;

- **Node.js** frontend server running Sapper/Svelte on `localhost:3000` and a
- **Django** (not DjangoRestFramework), backend running on `localhost:8000`.

My **Django** sessions are being cached using `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db` to a locally running Redis instance (and data forwarded to my Postgres instance).

I am handling my User model using `views` and `urls` I've defined in a **Django app**.

While building authentication; I am following the approach

- Run a `fetch()` POST'ing to `locahost:8000/login or signup`, using Django's `authenticate`, `login`, and `User.*` to create sessions.
- Then I return the `session_key` and `email` to the front-end which then sends these in the body for any request which may require authentication.
- In the backend, I match the `session_key` to the `user_id` using the e-mail sent to me in the request body to check if the session is valid.

Now since I have always used Django Templating, I hadn't had to ever maintain a separate session instance or had to think about sharing sessions. I feel this approach could be more python-ic.

At this stage, I've also had all the models, migrations done, this approach works, but seems to not be the best way to go about this.

Would appreciate feedback/critique.

Comment: It would help if you explained your dual-server architecture in more detail. Why can't you just use Django's standard session handling (e.g. SesssionMiddleware)? Your "In the backend..." section makes it sound like you're just reinventing Django's built-in session handling.

Comment: Appreciate the response, I am using Django's default SessionStorage, I use session objects (to validate if the user is active). My frontend is running on Express on a server which is independent to the Django instance which just serves endpoints. So sharing sessions aren't possible in the usual way? Like, how do you think I should be sharing sessions/keys.

Comment: I don't think there is much more you can do in terms of making it more Pythonic. You will always have to send something from the frontend to the Django backend to authenticate.

Comment: Agreed, this may be stupid, but how does this then differ from TokenAuth except for the way I send the session key and storage?

Comment: In production, would those two servers be on the same domain/port (with a reverse proxy/load balancer in front directing the requests to the right one based on the URL)? If so, session cookies would work out of the box, since as far as the browser is concerned it is talking to a single server, and for local development you can have your Express server pass through any unknown request to the Django backend, thus your browser only ever needs to talk to the Express server.

Comment: agree with André, you should use cookies. With cookies, the browser handles things for you, including security as it won't inadvertently send the cookie to the wrong server. You should also use CORS and use the Django plugin to implement a unique key in any POST you make to your server. Use CSP headers etc... Don't try to re-invent security, there are so many ways you can get hacked, just learn to use the framework and its plugins designed and battle-tested for this purpose.

Comment: Have your Django server serve the HTML body and deal with security, and plug the javascript build into it. The Svelte server should only be for development, then you build a JS bundle and serve it from static folder of the Django server.